# Simple Java constructor

Tags: java, constructor

For the following code lines:

```
public class Base{

    private int num1 = 0;
    private int num2 = 0;
    private static int dif = 0;

    public Base(int num){
         this(num,num+1);
         System.out.println("Base constructor1");
    }

    public Base(int num1, int num2){
         System.out.println("Base constructor2");
         this.num1 = num1;
         this.num2 = num2;
         dif = num2 - num1;
    }

    public int sum(){
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public static int getDif(){
        return dif;
    }
}
```

What should those 2 lines print ?

```
Base b1 = new Base(10);
Base b2 = new Base(4,7);
```

I think that if I'll understand the following line:     `this(num,num+1);` I will understand everything...

thnx

Comment: Do try and indent your code. Makes it much easier to read

Comment: this(num,num+1); calls public Base(int num1, int num2)

Comment: If you step through your code in a debugger you can see what each line does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this(num,num+1);
```

calls following constructor in same object

```
public Base(int num1, int num2){
```

Why?

If user created an object for `Base` by calling constructor with single param, your code does some default calculations in above constructor and sets `num2` and `diff` values.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement `Base b1 = new Base(10);` is an example of constructor chaining and it would produce following result -

```
Base constructor2 

Base constructor1
```

And second one is simple. It would print

```
Base constructor2
```

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question. "What would those 2 lines print?"

Answer (score 0):

```
Base b1 = new Base(10);
Base b2 = new Base(4,7);
```

This will print out:

> Base constructor2
>
> Base constructor1
>
> Base constructor2

Since the constructors are chained, the first constructor is called with the instantiation of `b1` (`public Base(int num1)`) which calls the other constructor (`public Base(int num1, int num2)`), which prints out "Base constructor2", then the execution returns to print out "Base constructor1".

`b2` is then instantiated and only prints out "Base constructor2" because the constructor that is used does not chain to another constructor.

Comment: @Lunar: I believe I was in the middle of updating when you posted this comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing one integer parameter in the first call:

```
Base b1 = new Base(10);
```

It will call the constructor with only one integer parameter and print out:

```
Base constructor1
```

The second call passes in two integer parameters so it will call the constructor with two integer parameters and print out:

```
Base constructor2
```

I suggest testing things yourself, trying things can be the easiest way to learn and understand better.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function that has multiple definitions, like

```
public Base(int num)
```

vs

```
public Base(int num1, int num2)
```

The one chosen is based on what parameters you use. So, by calling

```
new Base(5);
```

You'll hit the first constructor, with only a single int.

This constructor says, "well, I want both defined, but I only have one number.  Lets call the second constructor, and just make `num2` equal to this first number plus one.

```
this(num,num+1); //num == 5
```

calls

```
Base(int num1, int num2)
```

where `num1 == 5` which was provided, and `num2 == 6`, which was the provided number plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to run those two lines you would see...

```
Base constructor2
Base constructor1
Base constructor2
```

In your console because the first object declaration would call one constructor then the other, while the second declaration would only call the second constructor.